# Set mute button to always mute in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, mute

Does anyone know of any hacks for OSX that will set the mute button to always mute rather than toggle?  I would feel much better knowing that when I am hitting the mute button to avoid producing any sound, I will not accidentally be turning the sound back on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do this using the built-in tools in OS X.  You can however do this pretty easily in applescript:

```
$ osascript -e 'set volume output muted true'
```

There are a few utilities that can execute scripts like these - perhaps you already use [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) or [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/)?

If not, [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) is specifically meant to assign keyboard shortcuts to Applescript, so you could basically find F9 to that command above and hit FN+MUTE and it would mute every time.